# Why isn't my JS redirecting the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, google-search

I'm trying to make a HTML form that on submit does a google search with JS.

This is the HTML:

```
<form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="searchBox" onkeyup="changeLogo()" autofocus>
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="googleSearch()">
</form>
```

And the JS function:

```
function googleSearch() {
    var searchText = document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
    window.location.href = "http://google.com/";
}
```

The Google URL isn't right but it isn't redirecting at all.. I put alert(searchText) in the function and the alert showed so not really sure what's going on.

Comment: The syntax seems fine, so I suggest trying `document.location.href` instead `window` maybe some of your JS code is replacing that one ? Otherwise, you should be showing us the URL causing the issues so we can look at it.

Comment: On loading the URL is http://127.0.0.1:53841/   and once I submit it just submits the form http://127.0.0.1:53841/?search=test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the page refreshed  when you click submit button before excuting `localtion.href` line

try change with your code like below

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="return false">
....
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use button type as 'submit', it will submit your form.

So you can change your button from

```
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="googleSearch()">`
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="googleSearch()">
```

It will work.

Comment: still just submits the form unfortunately :/

Comment: It could not submit, can you send your changed code?

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitted which might be the issue. Change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"` this will make sure the form is not submitted on click of this button